# Object specify error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to code an action bar for my android app and i defined my object to set the logo of the action bar to the default andorid icon before i update. When i run just that code, i get an error on the marked line.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class myabDemo extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myab_demo);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // ***Error appears here***
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the logs ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not `R.drawable.icon_launcher` but `R.drawable.ic_launcher` (At least i'm pretty sure you followed the tutorial that puts ic_launcher and not icon_launcher)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you received a `nullpointer exception`, since `actionBar` is null.

Add the code below:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```